# jQuery plugin overrides keypress events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [Jquery ImgAreaSelector](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) plugin in my site. I have a bunch of keypress triggers in my site, using jquery. Eg:

```
$(document).bind('keypress', 'S', function(){
   alert("You have pressed S key");
});
```

These work fine. However when I click the button that initializes the imageAreaSelector and as soon as I drag an area across the image, my keypress events are no longer captured. If I press 'S' after that, it does not show the alert. Does anyone know how to handle this in the plugin?

Comment: Maybe plugin stop in some way keypress event propagation. Can you share MCVE replicating issue? If i test it on http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/  the event is fired as expected  EDIT: indeed you are correct, once i drag area, the event is no more fired

Comment: As a side note, this isn't syntax to capture `S` key using native jQuery `bind()` method. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks for looking at this...I am checking the plugin code, but my expertise is not good enough to figure out what have change I need to make to have the event fired even after dragging...EDIT: Just saw your question now. Yes I am using a plugin. It is jquery hotkeys by John Resig.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the plugin you are using, removes the `keypress` event registry completely when you drag an area on the image. Look that here https://github.com/odyniec/imgareaselect/blob/master/jquery.imgareaselect.dev.js#L375

For this reason, your custom keypress event handler getting removed and no longer working. The fix for this problem is either to change the library :-) or to use the `onSelectEnd` callback of that library:

```
$('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
    onSelectEnd: function (img, selection) {
        // When you are done with the selection
        registerKeypressAgain();
    }
});
```

Now, `registerKeypressAgain()` method is nothing but:

```
function registerKeypressAgain() {
    $(document).bind('keypress', 'S', function(){
       alert("You have pressed S key");
    });
}
```

Comment: Ya, plugin unbind events. It is shame it isn't using namespaced event but maybe this is possible to set it in option, not sure. That's said, other possibility would be to bind event using javascript native method instead (depending expected browser support: `document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
    console.log(e.which);
}, false);`

Comment: There seems to be a `resetKeypress` param that can be set to false: `If set to <code>false</code>, this instance's keypress  event handler is not activated`

Comment: Yes, that's true. That can be an option

Comment: Your code works...but surprisingly only the first time..after registering the keypress event again. It works the first time when I press the key, not after that...I wonder whats going wrong now..

Comment: @DanCouper: I had already looked at the resetKeypress. It seems to be only available in the update() function...

Comment: Yes @DanCouper is correct. I first thought there is an option to prevent that but that's not the case :-|

Comment: I think the problem is with the hotkeys library I am using. I am using jquery.hotkeys by John Resig. Instead when I use the addEventListenerthat @A.Wolff mentioned then it works fine...

Comment: I would say the imageselect library is the one that's a broken implementation (particularly given who wrote hotkeys). It shouldn't be doing what it's doing, that's a bad bug. But drop whatever it is you need least I guess is the simplest solution ;)

Comment: @DanCouper: Duly noted :)